# CS0103 Error Message When Calling A method

Tags: c#

I am receiving this error in visual studio community 15 trying to compile the code below.  I have created a method named "PrintFirstElement" and I am trying to pass the variable myArray as an arguement to the method.  I am receiving an error saing that the name PrintFirstElement does not exist in this context.  Doesnt make any sense to me.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{ 
    class Arrays
    {
        public void PrintFirstElement(int[] a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The first element is {0}. /n", a[0]);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            PrintFirstElement(myArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `PrintFirstElement` is in another class, you'll need to statically reference it or create an instance to get to it.

Comment: And unrelated to the error `/n` should probably be `\n` (inside the `Console.WriteLine` call)? If you even need it at all (`WriteLine` automatically adds a linebreak)

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to call the `PrintFirstElement` method, which exists in your `Arrays` class, from another class -- `Program`; to do this, you either need to instantiate the `Arrays` class and qualify the method call with the name of the instance, or change the `PrintFirstElement` method to `static` and qualify the method call with the name of the class itself.

So, either do this:

```
int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var a = new Arrays(); // create an instance of the `Arrays` class
a.PrintFirstElement(myArray);
```

Or change your method to `public static void PrintFirstElement(int[] a)` and change the call in `Main` to `Arrays.PrintFirstElement(myArray);`.

Comment: Thanks Rory makes perfect sense.  Im working out of a book and there was a detail that wasnt very well explained so I see the error of my ways.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Rory.ap completely right. I just want to add some information to his answer. When you change your method to static, this method becomes known by memory. So you don't have to create the object for your method.

Comment: Thanks for the extra insight.  Much appreciated.